# Binding event to wxMenu instead of wxMenuItem

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, bind, connect

Im creating a dynamic MenuBar from xml file, and binding events to menu items using Connect().
Some menus does not have items inside, but needs to fire events.
Is there a way to attach an event handler to a wxMenu using Connect()?

**Im Using wxWidgets 2.8.8 & MS VC++ 6.0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive tried many things, but nothing worked out for me.
As a quick answaer ill quote *Vadim Zeitlin* from wx-widgets list:

> No, you shouldn't associate commands
>   directly to top level menus. This is
>   discouraged under all systems and is
>   not supported at all under some of
>   them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can trap `EVT_MENU_OPEN` (see [wxMenuEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu_event.html)).

Connecting it might look like this:

```
Connect(wxEVT_MENU_OPEN, wxMenuEventHandler(MyFrame::OnMenuOpen), 0, 0);
```