# C++ Dynamic WX Menu Bindings

Tags: wxwidgets

I am working with wxMenu, and want a a way to handle events.  I really only need something that handles events that happen when you click on a menu item.  Specifically, given an arbitrary function pointer (of the form void(*)(void)), I want to make it so that that function pointer is called when the given event happens.

The menus will not be known in advance, so event tables as I understand them are out.

I found Bind and Connect, but neither seems to work (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174584/binding-event-to-wxmenu-instead-of-wxmenuitem) for Connect).

Adding code:

```
class Menu : public wxMenu {
    public:
        void handle_event(wxCommandEvent& event) {
            volatile int i = 6; //to prevent this method being optimized out
            //breakpoint here that never gets hit
            //selecting a callback to call (based on event.GetID()) could go here
        }
};

//Later, in a function (menu is instance of Menu)
menu->Connect(
    wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,
    (wxObjectEventFunction)(&Menu::handle_event),
    NULL,menu
);
//Also tried:
menu->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,&(Menu::handle_event),menu);
```

Comment: Bind should work if you are using wxWidgets v2.9.  Why don't you post the code you have tried, and then we can possibly help you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First comment: Your naming convention is terribly confusing: Menu is a subclass of wxMenu and has an instance called menu. If I had to maintain this code, I would go mad.

Second comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here that you can't do with the 'normal' way of doing this?

The normal method is something like this:

Add options to an instance of the standard wxMenu class

```
myMenu.Append(IDM_Option1,"Option 1");
...
myMenu.Append(IDM_OPtionN,"OPtion N");
```

Bind the events

```
   Bind( wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, &myWindow::OnMenuEvent, this, 
            IDM_Option1, IDM_OptionN );
```

Handle the events

```
  myWindow::OnMenuEvent( wxCommandEvent& event )
  {
      switch ( event.GetId() ) {
           case IDM_Option1
           ...
```

This handles most every situation without requiring you to subclass wxMenu.

Comment: Naming: the names are actually more involved; I tried to simplify.  I had been trying to do something similar to the above, but it wasn't working.  As a possible factor: is it necessary it to have myWindow be a class of a particular type (e.g. derived from something), or will any old class do?  Thanks,

Comment: It is probably best for MyWindow to be a subclass of wxFrame - I have never tried to use anything else myself.

Comment: Hmmmm, I tried making it a subclass of the current frame, and that magically fixed everything.  Wow.  I really wish that were documented somewhere.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind a function with `void (*)(void)` signature directly as `Bind()` expects the event handler to be `void (*)(EventClass&)` where `EventClass` depends on the type of the event you are binding to, e.g. is `wxCommandEvent` in your case.

Of course, you're completely free to use `boost.bind`, `boost.lambda`, C++11 lambdas or just manually forward the call from a function taking an event argument to one not taking it, so using `Bind()` should work just fine for you.

Comment: That's basically what I was trying to do.  In the added code above, the handle_event method is supposed to intercept all menu clicking events.  It would then dispatch the void(*)(void) callbacks.  Adding that part would be easy; the main problem now is that, while it compiles and runs smoothly, the handle_event callback never seems to get hit.  Thanks,

Comment: Which version of wx do you use? I think there was a bug with the menu events not being sent to the menu itself but only its containing window (i.e. usually wxFrame containing wxMenuBar) which was fixed only relatively recently.

Comment: That sounds like what happened.  Have 2.9.3.

Comment: Try binding the event at wxFrame level then.

Comment: Recomend upgrading to v2.9.4  There is at least one nasty bug in v2.9.3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906733/wxlog-timstamp-5-hours-in-the-past