# wxStaticText::SetLabel() segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, wxwidgets

I'm new to wxWidgets and I wanted to make a simple GUI application (on ubuntu) for reference.

I created a simple window, added some buttons and in a button event handler I want to update a `wxStaticText` object's text on screen to indicate which button has been pressed.

However when I call the `SetLabel` or `SetLabelText` functions that `wxStaticText` inherits, then I get a segmentation fault.

Maybe I'm missing something and wxStaticText is just not able to have their label set and I need another control. But I couldn't find anything like that in the class list.

I'm using wxWidgets 3.1.4 from the codelite repositories.

MainFrame.cpp

```cpp
#include "MainFrame.h"
#include <iostream>

// segfaults/bugs with simple constants, needs to be static
static const char* TITLE;
const int MainFrame::PX = 30;
const int MainFrame::PY = 30;
const int MainFrame::SX = 400;
const int MainFrame::SY = 300;

MainFrame::MainFrame()
    : wxFrame(nullptr, static_cast<wxWindowID>(IDs::MainFrame), wxString(TITLE), wxPoint(PX, PY), wxSize(SX, SY))
{
    // create bar
    // no need to call delete. new is overloaded for wx elements.
    menuBar = new wxMenuBar();
    // create menues
    menuFile = new wxMenu();

    // menuitems file
    menuItemClose = new wxMenuItem(menuFile, static_cast<int>(IDs::MenuItemClose), "Exit", "Close the application");
    Connect(menuItemClose->GetId(), wxEVT_MENU, wxCommandEventHandler(MainFrame::onClickMenuItemClose));
    menuFile->Append(menuItemClose);

    // construct menu bar from menues
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "File");

    this->SetMenuBar(menuBar);

    // misc
    lbl_Text = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, "Press a button!");

    // create sizers
    gridSizer = new wxGridSizer(1, 5, wxSize(5,5));

    boxSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    boxSizer->Add(lbl_Text,
                    0, // make vectically un-stretchable
                    wxALL, // implicit top alignment, border all around
                    10 // border 10 px
    );
    boxSizer->Add(gridSizer, 1, wxEXPAND, 0);

    this->SetSizerAndFit(boxSizer);

    // create buttons
    v_btn_Buttons = std::make_unique<std::vector<wxButton*>>(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        wxString txt = wxString(fmt::format("Button{0}", (i+1)).c_str());
        std::cout << "Creating Button #" << i+1 << ", with label: " << txt << std::endl;
        wxButton* btn = new wxButton(this, static_cast<int>(IDs::Button1) + i, txt);
        btn->Connect(wxEVT_BUTTON, wxCommandEventHandler(MainFrame::onClickButton));
        v_btn_Buttons->push_back(btn);
        gridSizer->Add(btn);
    }
}

MainFrame::~MainFrame()
{
}

void MainFrame::onClickMenuItemClose(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    Close();
    // no call of evt.Skip() because we're done with it.
}

void MainFrame::onClickButton(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    wxString txt = wxString(fmt::format(
        "Pressed Button #{0} (ID: {1})",
        evt.GetId() - static_cast<int>(IDs::Button1),
        evt.GetId()
    ));
    lbl_Text->SetLabelText(txt);
}
```

MainFrame.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "pch.h"

class MainFrame : public wxFrame
{
private:
    // constants
    const char* TITLE = "My awesome title!";
    static const int PX;
    static const int PY;
    static const int SX;
    static const int SY;

private:
    // member variables

private:
    // Layout and Windows

    // layout using sizers
    /*
     * +-----------------+
     * | MENU            |
     * +-----------------+
     * |+---------------+|
     * ||BoxSizer (col) ||
     * ||TextLabel      ||
     * |+---------------+|
     * ||+-------------+||
     * |||GridSizer    |||
     * |||BTN|BTN|...  |||
     * ||+-------------+||
     * |+---------------+|
     * +-----------------+
    */

    // wxMenuBar { wxMenu {wxMenuItem,...}, ... }

    wxMenuBar*                                  menuBar         = nullptr;
    wxMenu*                                     menuFile        = nullptr;
    wxMenuItem*                                 menuItemClose   = nullptr;

    wxBoxSizer*                                 boxSizer        = nullptr;
    wxGridSizer*                                gridSizer       = nullptr;

    wxStaticText*                               lbl_Text        = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<wxButton*>>     v_btn_Buttons   = nullptr;

protected:
    // Event handlers
    void onClickMenuItemClose(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void onClickButton(wxCommandEvent& evt);

public:
    MainFrame();
    virtual ~MainFrame();

    // used to identify elements
    // can be extracted from events
    enum class IDs : wxWindowID
    {
        MainFrame       = 10000,
        MenuItemClose   = 10100,
        Button1         = 10500,
        Button2,
        Button3,
        Button4,
        Button5
    };

};
```

pch.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <vector>
#include <memory> // smart pointers

// will be in c++20 as
// #include <format>
#include <fmt/format.h>
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include "MainFrame.h"

// application class
class Main : public wxApp
{
public:
    // function called at the application initialization
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(Main);

bool Main::OnInit()
{
    // create a new frame and set it as the top most application window
    MainFrame* mainFrame = new MainFrame();
    SetTopWindow(mainFrame);

    // show main frame
    mainFrame->Show();

    // enter the application's main loop
    return true;
}
```

Compiled with

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j4 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ wxTest - Debug ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest'
/usr/bin/g++-10 -c  pch.h -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.1-unofficial3 -I/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
pch.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
    1 | #pragma once
      |         ^~~~
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest'
/usr/bin/g++-10 -include pch.h  -c  "/home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest/MainFrame.cpp" -g -O0 -pedantic -W -std=c++20 -fcoroutines -Wall -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.1-unofficial3 -I/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread  -o ../build-Debug/wxTest/MainFrame.cpp.o -I.
/usr/bin/g++-10 -include pch.h  -c  "/home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest/main.cpp" -g -O0 -pedantic -W -std=c++20 -fcoroutines -Wall -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.1-unofficial3 -I/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread  -o ../build-Debug/wxTest/main.cpp.o -I.
/home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest/main.cpp:13:20: warning: extra ';' [-Wpedantic]
   13 | IMPLEMENT_APP(Main);
      |                    ^
/home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest/MainFrame.cpp: In member function 'void MainFrame::onClickMenuItemClose(wxCommandEvent&)':
/home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest/MainFrame.cpp:63:54: warning: unused parameter 'evt' [-Wunused-parameter]
   63 | void MainFrame::onClickMenuItemClose(wxCommandEvent& evt)
      |                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/bin/g++-10 -o ../build-Debug/bin/wxTest @../build-Debug/wxTest/ObjectsList.txt -L.  -lfmt  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk3u_unofficial3_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk3u_unofficial3_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk3u_unofficial3_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk3u_unofficial3_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_unofficial3_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_unofficial3_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu_unofficial3-3.1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest'
====0 errors, 3 warnings, total time: 00:00:18 seconds====
```

I get the following stacktrace when I click a button:

```
0  0x0000555555950050  ??    
1  0x0000555555566e85  MainFrame::onClickButton  /home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest/MainFrame.cpp  77
2  0x00007ffff758f091  wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../include/wx/app.h  462
3  0x00007ffff758f091  wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../src/common/event.cpp  1400
4  0x00007ffff758f52e  wxEvtHandler::SearchDynamicEventTable  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../src/common/event.cpp  1897
5  0x00007ffff758f8b4  wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../src/common/event.cpp  1618
6  0x00007ffff758f95f  wxEvtHandler::TryBeforeAndHere  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../include/wx/event.h  3927
7  0x00007ffff758f95f  wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../src/common/event.cpp  1555
8  0x00007ffff758fa61  wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../src/common/event.cpp  1528
9  0x00007ffff7590f8b  wxEvtHandler::SafelyProcessEvent  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../src/common/event.cpp  1646
10  0x00007ffff7be5db0  wxWindowBase::HandleWindowEvent  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../include/wx/window.h  852
11  0x00007ffff7a1ba02  wxgtk_button_clicked_callback  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../src/gtk/button.cpp  38
12  0x00007ffff62dba56  ??    
13  0x00007ffff62fab28  g_signal_emit_valist    
14  0x00007ffff62fb0d3  g_signal_emit    
15  0x00007ffff68f92ae  ??    
16  0x00007ffff68f9318  ??    
17  0x00007ffff62db802  g_closure_invoke    
18  0x00007ffff62ef962  ??    
19  0x00007ffff62fab9e  g_signal_emit_valist    
20  0x00007ffff62fb0d3  g_signal_emit    
21  0x00007ffff68f7754  ??    
22  0x00007ffff6ba8a71  ??    
23  0x00007ffff62dba56  ??    
24  0x00007ffff62fab28  g_signal_emit_valist    
25  0x00007ffff62fb0d3  g_signal_emit    
26  0x00007ffff69bff5c  ??    
27  0x00007ffff62dec56  g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__BOXEDv    
28  0x00007ffff62dba56  ??    
29  0x00007ffff62fab28  g_signal_emit_valist    
30  0x00007ffff62fb0d3  g_signal_emit    
31  0x00007ffff69bcfa2  ??    
32  0x00007ffff69be5eb  ??    
33  0x00007ffff69c15d6  ??    
34  0x00007ffff6988bb0  gtk_event_controller_handle_event    
35  0x00007ffff6b4b0fd  ??    
36  0x00007ffff6ba248b  ??    
37  0x00007ffff62db802  g_closure_invoke    
38  0x00007ffff62eef96  ??    
39  0x00007ffff62fa45d  g_signal_emit_valist    
40  0x00007ffff62fb0d3  g_signal_emit    
41  0x00007ffff6b4cbb3  ??    
42  0x00007ffff6a080b8  ??    
43  0x00007ffff6a0a36b  gtk_main_do_event    
44  0x00007ffff66f2f79  ??    
45  0x00007ffff6726106  ??    
46  0x00007ffff61effbd  g_main_context_dispatch    
47  0x00007ffff61f0240  ??    
48  0x00007ffff61f0533  g_main_loop_run    
49  0x00007ffff6a0930d  gtk_main    
50  0x00007ffff79b0e95  wxGUIEventLoop::DoRun  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../src/gtk/evtloop.cpp  64
51  0x00007ffff7445731  wxEventLoopBase::Run  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../src/common/evtloopcmn.cpp  90
52  0x00007ffff740fa2a  wxAppConsoleBase::MainLoop  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../src/common/appbase.cpp  380
53  0x00007ffff749a83a  wxEntry  /home/david/devel/packages/wx/3.1.4/wxwidgets3.1-3.1.4/objs_gtk_sh/../include/wx/app.h  462
54  0x000055555558c082  main  /home/paul/Documents/Projects/wxTest/main.cpp  13
55  0x00007ffff6f910b3  __libc_start_main  /build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c  308
56  0x000055555556625e  _start
```

Comment: `// segfaults/bugs with simple constants, needs to be static` suggests that you may have hidden a bug. Maybe the same bug you are fighting with now. Maybe a different bug. Hard to say.

Comment: @user4581301 I thought it was due to the constants being declared but not initialized during the initilizer list/base ctor call, providing uninitialized variables to the base ctor call.

Comment: Save yourself a compiler warning by changing `void MainFrame::onClickMenuItemClose(wxCommandEvent& evt)` to `void MainFrame::onClickMenuItemClose(wxCommandEvent& )`. If you don't give the parameter a name, the compiler knows it's not used in the function even though the function still requires the argument..

Comment: @user4581301 wx provides a function/macro `wxUnusedVar();` which is used all over the examples. I implemented that now. But it's not related.

Comment: @FalcoGer, where exactly the crash happens? Did you debug the code?

Comment: @Igor The crash happens when I press a button. Stacktrace indicates line 77 (the `lbl_text->SetLabel()` call. `SetLabelText` produces the same result.) If I comment that line out, nothing happens. I used gdb on it and it gives me the same result.

Comment: What is the value of `lbl_text`? Does it make sense?

Comment: When the debugger halts and spits out the stack trace, does the address `lbl_text` contains make any sense?

Comment: indeed. `lbl_Text` is garbage (0x0, 0x21, 0x100000001, etc) at that time. I have no idea why

Comment: First thing to do is  make sure `this` is still a sane value. Assuming it is, step your way through `MainFrame`s constructor to make sure `lbl_Text` got through the constructor intact. Then make sure it's still valid at `mainFrame->Show();`. If `this` is not sane, could be a lot of digging involed. I don't have the wx tools installed on my box otherwise I'd join in the hunt.

Comment: @FalcoGer, you need to switch to using `Bind()` instead of `Connect()`, then you will see what is happenning. `btn->Bind( wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainFrame::onClickButton, this );` - try this instead of an ugly `Connect()` call. `Connect()` should be deprecated very soon and should be used for BC only in the old code.

Comment: @Igor That did it. Though I don't understand. Also how do I bind the menuitem to a callback function without Connect? wxMenuItem has neither Bind nor Connect as a member.

Comment: @FalcoGer, simple - just change `Connect()` to `Bind()`, get rid of that ugly cast and use proper event sink. Now do you understand why the code is working now?

Comment: @Igor No. I don't get it. I can't find any reference in the manual for wxMenu or wxMenuItem. Also I don't know why `Connect` would give this unintuitive and broken behavior while `Bind` does not. Also I don't understand what cast you are talking about. The only cast I do is from my enum class to wxWindowId, because i want to have my ids named and not declare constants without a scope for those.

Comment: @Igor NVM I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327098/c-dynamic-wx-menu-bindings

Comment: @FalcoGer, `Connect()` would also work provided you supply a proper `event sink` parameter. `Bind()` can catch those errors. The cast I'm talking about is the casting of the function handler - with Bind() you jkust need a name, with Connect you need to cast it to the proper type. Just look at your Connect() call and compare it with my Bind() one. Looks much nicer.

Comment: Okay. Supply your answer and I will accept. Also whoever downvoted, I'd like to know why.

Comment: Trying to reason about downvotes is usually wasted time.

Comment: I just wish to post better questions, not blame anyone.

Comment: Understood. If you can see the close votes on your question, use them as a guide. If you can't, there's one vote for not enough debugging information. This connects with the big thing I would have done differently: inspected the values of variables earlier and reported them in the question body. Knowing that `lbl_Text` was broken inside the event handler may have gotten an answer quicker from an early viewer who recognized the behaviour and went looking for the `connect` call. Otherwise there's a couple hundred lines of code and a stack trace, making the question pretty ignorable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to see because there is too much code here (you should try to reduce your examples as much as possible, by removing all the unrelated parts), but the root cause of your problem is this line:

```
        btn->Connect(wxEVT_BUTTON, wxCommandEventHandler(MainFrame::onClickButton));
```

Here you're connecting a method of `MainFrame` to a `wxButton` object, which ends up calling a class method on an object of a wrong class with the expectedly fatal results.

You need to provide the frame pointer (i.e. `this`) as `Connect()` `eventSink` argument in order to call it on the right object. Alternatively, you could call `this->Connect()` as then the object being connected to and the object used for the call is the same.

Finally, to ensure that you don't make such mistakes in the future, don't use `Connect()` at all, but use the type-safe `Bind()` instead. If you used it here, this call wouldn't have compiled, rather than crashed during run-time.